# MFC: why DrawText adds empty line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Here is how I do to display text. I first use `DT_CALCRECT` to get the rect for the text.

```
pDC->DrawText(text, &rc, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT | DT_CALCRECT);
```

Then apply the same setting for the actual drawing.

```
pDC->DrawText(text, rc, DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_LEFT);
```

What I found strange is: sometimes the text shows completely in one line which means the width is wide enough, but there is still an empty line following it. I suspect it tries to do word break but there is really nothing at the end of the text, no trailing whitespaces of any kind.

Comment: Is it possible you have a newline (`\n`) character at the end of your text?

Comment: As I have checked, no whitespace of any kind (\n \r \t ...).

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you are seeing? Also, how are `pDC`, `rc`, and `text` being initialized before `DrawText()` is called?

Comment: We need a worked example really. Your line of code is fine but we don't know the contents of your variable and we don't know the output. Nor do we know the context of your `DrawText` line in your code.

Comment: How do you know that there is empty line?

Comment: Well, when trying to prepare mre, I finally locate the bug: in the code of DT_CALCRECT, I forget to select font, while in real drawing I select font. Thanks!